# CMake: different operations with different build type

Tags: cmake

I want to add some specific flags when I compile in debug mode (GCC/Linux). When I call cmake I want to print all these flags. If I compile in Release mode I don't set these so I don't want to print flags.

Basically I want to print a message only if I build in Debug mode.

In my CMakefile.txt I've following code:

```
# Setting compiler
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set (USER_DEBUG_FLAGS "-W -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Werror")
  message(STATUS "Setting extra flags for Linux compiler")
  if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${USER_DEBUG_FLAGS})
    message(STATUS "Debug compiler flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG")
  endif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
```

If i call cmake with

```
cmake /path/to/CMakefile.txt/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

I see the first message (so Linux compiler is recognized) but I cannot see the second message.

How can I check if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to Debug or Release?

Comment: There is a missing `}` on line 7.

Comment: On the other hand, you should not need to check `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` is only used in the Debug configuration. In fact, in multi-config build systems like Visual Studio, this is plain wrong.

Comment: @Lindydancer thanks but problem remains. I know that I should not use it with multi-config systems. I'm doing only for gcc.

Comment: Try printing `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}`. (Also, you can use `if(... STREQUAL ...)` rather than `MATCHES`, both work but the later work with Regexp:s which is a bit of an overkill.)

Comment: STREQUAL worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: Note that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is not used when using a multi-config generator, where one should instead used the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression, which is evaluated when _generating each buildsystem_ and not when configuring cmake.